# What is the significance of following?

Tags: extjs

I'm very new to EXTJS.I want to know the concepts of following.

```
       Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'folder_closed.gif';
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    Ext.form.VTypes["nameVal"]  = /^([A-Z]{1})[A-Za-z\-]+ ([A-Z]{1})[A-Za-z\-]+/;
    Ext.form.VTypes["nameMask"] = /[A-Za-z\- ]/;
    Ext.form.VTypes["nameText"] = 'In-valid Director Name.';
    Ext.form.VTypes["name"]     = function(v){
        return Ext.form.VTypes["nameVal"].test(v);
```

and also what does the `"renderTo:document.body"` do ....?

Comment: update your post again, i think a big part of the example has disappeared. And be a little more specific about your first question.

Comment: @Chris: I'll update the exact code in next new post.Can you please explain the commands which i've mentioned above n other commands too.

Answer (score 1):

The first bit of code registers a so-called [`vtype`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.VTypes) which is a validation-element that can be used to validate to textfield form elements simply by applying a `vtype`-attribute. In your case the `vtype`-name would be `name`.

```
{
    ...
    xtype: "textfield",
    vtype: "name",
    ...
}
```

The `renderTo` property does the following (from the ExtJS documentation):

> Specify the id of the element, a DOM
>   element or an existing Element that
>   this component will be rendered into.

Although the learning curve is steep with ExtJS, you should read the API documentation - almost all questions can be answered from there (including both of your questions).

Comment: Thank u.I'll let u know here,if any doubts further.

Comment: @user654787: Would be nice to mark the answer as "accepted". This is common practice in StackOverflow and helps other users with the same questions.